# Is there difference between value of Scopus- or ISI-indexed paper in gaining acceptance for PhD?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Is there difference between value of Scopus- or ISI-indexed paper in gaining acceptance for PhD?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Academia SE. Please ask each question as a separate StackExchange question. The reason is that you will have to accept one answer as the best, accepted one, so if you are asking two things at a time, it is possible two different answers answer the two questions best. This will be confusing for future readers.

Comment: I've deleted the second question. Feel free to ask it separately. You may want to add a small amount of context to this question.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the US, PhD admissions committees do not care whether the journal an applicant has published in happens to be on one list or another (there are plenty of really low-quality journals in both of those lists, and high-quality journals not in them). Rather, they care whether the journal is reputable and highly regarded, and whether the paper itself is any good.

**tl;dr** Aim to publish solid, high-quality work in a journal that is known for publishing solid, high-quality work.

Comment: In my experience, this is also true of faculty hiring committees and tenure/promotion committees.

Comment: really nice answer 